# How can those node modules which use native code be used in browser?

Tags: javascript, encryption, browser, rsa, browserify

Some node modules like 'ursa' uses native code. I had a requirement to use it in browser so I bundled it with `browserify` but it did not do well. I got some errors which I found that was due to the fact that **ursa** usages native codes which was not found in the browser scope. So the question is how I can use modules like **ursa** in browser that uses natives.

Comment: You probably will need to either provide your configuration or a more detailed error in order to get much help. But it looks like that module just can't be used on the browser. I don't know much about it though so maybe somebody else can prove me wrong :)

Comment: In general you cannot use node modules having native code in the browser. For some modules it might be possible to find a work around, but not with a certain amount of manual refactoring.

Comment: @t.niese, so what exactly is that work around? I want to know that.

Comment: @nurulnabi that depends on the modules, certain modules have native code only for a small portion of code that might be not necessary in a browser environment. And you could replace this code by native js code. But there is no general way to do that. You need to check this for each of those modules manually.